# log4net Not logging to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I've followed [This Tutorial](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) to the letter, yet when I call my API nothing is logged and no log file is created.

I have added the package.
I have created a log4net config file to my project.

```
<log4net>
   <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
  <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <file value="C:\Users\User-1\Desktop\Logs" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
     <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

   <!--Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1--> 
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="A1" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I have added a reference to that config file to my web.config file

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
```

And finally I have added the logger to my controller

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Info("Get Object Requested");
```

I've also included this in my AssemblyInfo file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: You say `web.config`, your project is a web application? Possibly running under different credentials? Try writing to directory is not restricted to one user, i.e. c:\temp

Comment: First XML doesn't seem valid. Check your commenting.  <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender --> <!--A1 uses PatternLayout --> <!--Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->

Comment: Are you missing the call to `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` to load the config? Is the log4net config file set to be copied the output on project build?

Comment: "Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1" seems to be a comment too, but is not in the <!-- --> tags.

Comment: An easy way to find the problem is to [use log4net internal debugging](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)

Comment: @Gokhan Good eye! I've updated that but It's still not logging.

Comment: Do you have a configsection for log4net in your web.config and the following below? <log4net configSource="log4net.config" />

Comment: Also is your log4net.config coming along with the rest into your buildfolder?

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the link, I followed the tutorial and managed to figure it out. It was something to do with not having sufficient permissions to the folder.

Comment: @JackTyler  A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender  row still uncommented.